# Data saving as blank in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-model

I have a foreach loop that saves a bunch of records into a table using cakePHP

```
foreach($interests as $id){
                $this->data['UserInterest']['user_id'] = $user_id;
                $this->data['UserInterest']['interest_id'] = $id;
                $this->data['UserInterest']['other_interest'] = $other;
                $UserInterest = new UserInterest;
                if(!$UserInterest->save($this->data)) {
                    $this->Session->setFlash(__l('Failed to save Interests.') , 'default', null, 'error');
                }
            }
```

All saves fine except the other interest

UPDATE:

I've did the following

I can exho it out perfectly if I do this

```
$this->data['UserInterest']['other_interest'] = $other;
echo $this->data['UserInterest']['other_interest'];
                    $UserInterest = new UserInterest;
```

But somehow it saves as blank?

My database layout looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users_interests` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `interest_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `other_interest` varchar(150) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

and my model like this

```
<?php
class UserInterest extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'UserInterest';

    var $useTable="users_interests";

    //$validate set in __construct for multi-language support
    //The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed
    var $belongsTo = array(
        'User' => array(
            'className' => 'User',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
        ) ,
        'Interests' => array(
            'className' => 'Interest',
            'foreignKey' => 'interest_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
        )
    );
    function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) 
    {
        parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);
        $this->validate = array(
            'user_id' => array(
                'rule' => 'numeric',
                'allowEmpty' => false,
                'message' => __l('Required')
            )
        );
    }
}
?>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

UPDATE:

I did the following

```
$this->data['UserInterest']['user_id'] = $user_id;
                $this->data['UserInterest']['interest_id'] = $id;
                $this->data['UserInterest']['other_interest'] = $other;
                 echo '<pre>';
                var_dump($this->data['UserInterest']);
                var_dump($other);
                var_dump($this->data['UserInterest']['other_interest']);

                $this->UserInterest = ClassRegistry::init('UserInterest');
```

And the var_dump results where the following, and still it did not save

```
array(3) {
  ["user_id"]=>
  string(3) "659"
  ["interest_id"]=>
  string(2) "10"
  ["other_interest"]=>
  string(17) "Share Investments"
}
string(17) "Share Investments"
string(17) "Share Investments"
```

Comment: Not sure if this will solve your problem, but there are better ways to initialize your model! In controller class, you can use $uses array in class definition like this: $uses = array('UserInterest'); Some people don't like this, since it can take a lot of memory. In that case you can do this instead:  $this->UserInterest = ClassRegistry::init('UserInterest'); Try these things instead of doing $UserInterest = new UserInterest; and see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks, was worth the shot but it did not do the trick, I've updated my Question

Comment: The weirdest thing is that only that one field won't save. Only other thing I can think of is that it is having some difficulty with that field because of those keywords like CHARACTER SET and COLLATE which you're using. Can you recreate the table without that and see if it works? (or add a new varchar field without any keywords)

Comment: @user470714 - Ok, problem solved, the problem was that in before filter, I have function beforeFilter()
    {
        $this->Security->disabledFields = array('User.other_interest'); I removed this and then it worked. I can kick myself. Anyway thanks for the help, much appreciated

Comment: Lol, I guess I would have never guessed that, but I'm happy you found it out.

Answer (score 1):

And old post but would like to add this here....

Always have

```
$this->Modelname->create();
```

in loops to save multiple records with loop. An most often this is the case which causes the error.